# Accessing the number of arguments pass into a docker run command script

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile

I have a docker Entrypoint script that looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
LABEL=$1
mkdir -p /backup/$LABEL
...
```

I can access the arguments passed in the normal bash way via $1, $2, etc. but I also need to know the number of arguments passed in.  At first I thought I could do this like this:

```
if [ $# -eq 2 ];
  then
```

However that does not work.  Any ideas on how to retrieve the number of arguments?

TIA,
Ole

Comment: How did you confirm `that does not work`?  Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: This should work in normal cases. Be we don't have any idea about how parameters are passed to the script, what you pass, and what you get?

Comment: I put an echo on $#.  It is zero.  To see for yourself just build a simple image and echo $#.  Everything echoed from the Entrypoint script is reported on the console.

Comment: Please update the question with the above information. I haven't used docker so far so can't help myself with  `just build a simple image and echo $#`. :( In a normal bash script, `echo #?` should give you the total number of parameters passed to the script..

Comment: `echo #?` returns blank for me even outside of the docker environment.  `$#` does return the correct number of arguments outside the docker environment.  I switched to using the following check for the third parameter instead of using the total number of parameters: `if [ -z "$RESTORE" ]`, so that gets me around the issue.  Would still be nice to have an answer though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - In reality nothing passed in was resolving.  The reason is that the entrypoint line needs to look like this:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["bash", "/run.sh"]
```

Mine looked like this:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/run.sh"]
```

See here for more info:
[Referencing the first argument passed to the docker entrypoint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37378616/referencing-the-first-argument-passed-to-the-docker-entrypoint)

Answer (score 1):

Weird. This should work. But, if you can read the positional parameters `$1` and `$2`, you may have luck looping over them:

```
#!/bin/bash

params="$@"
while param=$1 && [ -n "$param" ]
do
    shift
    ((count += 1))
    echo "here comes $param"
done

echo "All params: ${params[@]}"
echo "We saw $count of them"
```